# WiX installer remove files on uninstall but not on upgrade

Tags: wix, windows-installer, upgrade, uninstallation, delete-file

I have a program that installs with a WiX installer.

The program itself creates a number of files in the [CommonAppDataFolder]\[MyAppName]\ directory. These files all have the same extension (lets call it .dat).

On **upgrading**, I want to **retain** these files.
On **uninstalling**, I want to **remove** these files.

I am currently deleting the files as so:

```
<Directory Id='CommonAppDataFolder'>
  <Directory Id='MyCommonAppDataFolder' Name='MyAppName'>
    <Component Id='RemoveFilesComponent' Guid='71cb0cd8-8459-4a8f-89b7-f00977aa7b70'>
      <RemoveFile Id='RemoveFiles' Name='*.dat' On='uninstall'/>
    </Component>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

And I have this to facilitate upgrades:

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallInitialize'/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Now, when I uninstall, the .dat files are removed correctly.
However, when I upgrade, the .dat files are also removed. I guess because an upgrade is performing an uninstall on the previous version.

Am I approaching this problem correctly? How can I retain the files on upgrade, while removing them on uninstall?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Long time ago, but not that I can remember. I think I ended up just leaving the files in the CommonAppDataFolder after an uninstall.

Comment: Thanks Matt for answering.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding a condition to the RemoveExistingProducts? This is what I would do.

```
<RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallInitialize'>(NOT UPGRADINGPRODUCTCODE) AND (Installed)</RemoveExistingProducts>
```

Comment: This seems like what I want, but of course it means that the previous version isn't removed on upgrading. For example, I end up with multiple entries for my application in the 'Add or Remove Programs' control panel. Any workaround?

Comment: You could try the remove existing product to After InstallFinalize. This would remove any changed files and registry settings but keep what you didn't. IT could also have to do with you ProductID or version. The OS probably thinks it's a different program entirely.

Comment: Is upgrade internaly does uninstallation and reinstallation? or is it overwrite dlls/files?

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to switch to a minor update. That has a lot of restrictions so it isn't as easy as it sounds.

Comment: Your answer might be before or in the early stages of wix burn so I'm wondering if you would or could now answer this question differently. Is a possible solution to create a wix bootstrapper with 2 msi packages. His .dat files would be in the second msi package and does not get upgraded.

Comment: Lots of things could be done if the original package shipped differently. I answered assuming he needed to deal with what shipped.

Comment: @RobMensching is there an answer to not shipped packages? (currently on development) It would be very helpful. Thanks!